# Laravel 4 Query groupBy: all columns from table

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I have to call the `$model->groupBy(?allcols?)` function with all columns as a param.

How should I do this?

**Edit:** I have all Columns as an Array, so i can't pass them like 'col1','col2',...

I'm asking this because i have this [poblem (github)](https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator/issues/460) and i found out, that there the prob is on [Line 119](https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator/blob/master/src/Frozennode/Administrator/DataTable/DataTable.php#L119). 
I tried it manually like col1,col2 which worked, but it should by dynamically for all models.

I found this [snippet](http://laravelsnippets.com/snippets/get-all-columns-names-from-a-eloquent-model-2), to get all cols from the current table as an array, but i can only pass a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if I'm understanding your edit correctly, you've got an array of column names you wish to group by.  If `$model` is the name of your query, I'd recommend just using a `foreach` loop and appending each field:

```
foreach($allcols as $col){
    $model->groupBy($col);
}
$model->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function for grouping all columns but you may use `groupBy(col1, col2, ...)`, for example, if you have a `posts` table then you may use:

```
DB::table('posts')->groupBy('col1', 'col2')->get();
```

Or using `Eloquent` Model, for example a `Post` model:

```
Post::groupBy('col1', 'col2')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is get rid of duplicate records (which is all that `groupBy(all)` would do as far as I can envision), you could also just use `$model->distinct()` instead.  However, unless you add a `select()` to exclude the `id` field, you're going to wind up with the full recordset with no grouping, as by definition the id is unique to each record and thus won't collapse across records by either manner.